# In case of nested loops, what happens in case of multiple print outputs?

Tags: java, if-statement, methods, static, void

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        print(4);
    }

    static void print(int n){
        if (n <= 1)
            System.out.print("A");
        else {
            print(n-1);
            print(n-2);
        }
    }
}
```

The output result of this code is AAAAA. But I want to know how? When do I consider `(n-1)` and when `(n-2)`?

Comment: Please properly indent your code.

Comment: When asking for help, it's a good idea to indent and format your code in a readable, consistent way. (It's a good idea when *not* asking for help, too.) (Edit: Stefan and I have done it for you this time.)

Comment: By far the best way to answer this sort of question is to use the debugger built into your IDE. Run the code in debug mode, step through the statements one by one, look at the values of variables, etc. Note that this is a *recursive* function (not a nested one), and so note that you'll have more than one `n` to keep track of (each call gets its *own* `n`).

Comment: @Stultuske sorry, I just started coding 2 weeks ago. would be nice to hear someone's explanation.

Comment: @nerv21 if you only started two weeks ago, chances are you are just rushing. do you know what the lines you wrote do? do you know what primitives and objects are, and how they differ? do you understand what static is, and why you need it to get your code (as is) to run? my advice, go look into the documentation of the methods you use, to see what they actually do. then, go through your code, just in your head, and check the order in which your code executes.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the title of the question is wrong. There are no loops in your code, only recursion.

Now, to analyze the output, let's see what calls each method makes:

```
print(4)
    calls print(3)
        calls print(2)
            calls print(1) which prints 1st A
            calls print(0) which prints 2nd A
        calls print(1) which prints 3rd A
    calls print(2)
        calls print(1) which prints 4th A
        calls print(0) which prints 5th A
```

A total of 5 `"A"`s are printed.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is recursively calling the print(int n) method - Recursion is the technique of a method calling itself to solve a problem. In math, you may express this as f(x) = f(x-1) + f(x-2).

`print(4)
        print(3)
            print(2)
                print(1)
                    System.out.print("A")
                print(0)
                    System.out.print("A")
            print(1)
                System.out.print("A")
        print(2)
            print(1)

                System.out.print("A")
            print(0)
                System.out.print("A")`

What you will observes is that the function will print f(n+2) "A"s, for which f(x) is the fibonacci sequence where x is an integer greater than or equal to 0.

Answer (score 0):

I hope below image will help you to visualize the output-

```
                     print(4)
                     /     \
             print(3)       print(2)
             /   \          /     \
        print(2) print(1) print(1) print(0)
        /   \       |       |       |   
 print(1)  print(0) |       |       |   
    |         |     |       |       |   
    A         A     A       A       A
```

Comment: Thanks you so much!